# What Conservative Catholic publication am I looking for?

Tags: catholicism, resource-request

Some months ago, I stumbled on an online publication, whose name I cannot remember - and I  believe they also offer a printed subscription.  In spite of multiple google and wiki searches, I have been unable to restumble on it.  What I remember about it is this: It had a rather arch, playfully academic tone. For example, in one of it own blurbs, it quoted a well known, liberal Catholic bishop, referring to the publication as a defamatory screed.  In other words, the condemnation of this person was held up as an encomium by the editors.

The other thing that comes to mind is that it used a seraphed font.

Comment: What country is this in?

Comment: Oh. Well if you had said this was a US publication...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is the [New Oxford Review](http://www.newoxfordreview.org/), which is available online or in print.  I can imagine it being described by a liberal bishop as a 'defamatory screed,' but I can find no evidence of it on the site.

The [National Catholic Register](http://www.ncregister.com/) (U.S.) is a kind of conservative/orthodox counterbalance to the lamentably heterodox National Catholic Reporter.  Again, print edition offered.

It might help if you could remember what kind of publication it was -- news, commentary, etc.

Comment: Welcome! Thanks for contributing. If you haven't already done so, I hope you'll take a minute to take the [tour] and learn [how this site is different from others](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/a/1809/21576).  The NOR, at the top of its home page, quotes [Rembert Weakland](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rembert_Weakland) as calling it "very offensive!"  That might be exactly it.

Comment: Some others include: [_The Remnant_](http://remnantnewspaper.com/), [_The Wanderer_](http://www.thewandererpress.com/ee/wandererpress/index.php#), [_Angelus_](http://www.angelusonline.org/), [_Latin Mass Magazine_](http://latinmassmagazine.nj.newsmemory.com/).

Comment: Thank you! It is the New Oxford Review.  And it's not defamatory screed, but in the upper right hand corner, we read, ' "Very Offensive!" - Archbishop Rembert Weakland'.  As another example of the cheeky style, see the "Rebuttal to Hurtful Ads"

Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

This seems to describe the *Catholic Herald,* which is conservative, does offer a print subscription and does use a serif font. [catholicherald.co.uk](http://www.catholicherald.co.uk/)

[image: Front cover of 4 December issue]